# Run PIP installed library in same Dockerfile during image build

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, dockerfile

I need to install a PIP library in my docker image and run it from the very same Dockerfile.

Example:

```
from python

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -U -r ete3

RUN 'python3 -c "from ete3 import NCBITaxa;NCBITaxa();"'


CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "-c", "gunicorn_conf.py", "api.main:app"]
```

running this fails with

```
/bin/sh: 1: python3 -c "import ete3": not found
The command '/bin/sh -c 'python3 -c "from ete3 import NCBITaxa;NCBITaxa();"'' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

however, if I remove the `RUN` directive, finish the build, attach to the running container
`python3 -c "from ete3 import NCBITaxa;NCBITaxa();"` will work.

I assume since its pip and installed into `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ete3` it should be in the `PYTHONPATH`? Or is it that because this is at image build time the system is not yet available? Any tricks?

I need this functionality to pull some NCBI database updates at build time into the image so that this `ete3` library is up2date for deployment. `ete3` would pull the files at runtime and that is slow and terrible.

One alternative could be to prebuild an image with the PIP library installed from `Dockerfile1` and run the update in `Dockerfile2` ?

Comment: why are you running an import command in a shell?

Comment: oh yes, it was just the minimal test without the main logic. I realize that is not good for here. Let me change it...

Comment: The `RUN` command is in single quotes, so when Docker invokes a shell to run it, the shell looks for the whole string – spaces and embedded double quotes and all – as the filename for the command to run.  Does removing the outer single quotes, just `RUN python3 -c "..."`, make this work better?

Comment: I will try fiddling with the quotes! Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the commands you want to run into a python script like `something.py`.

Your `something.py` file can look like,

```
import eta3
...
...
...
```

Then change the last line to this,

```
CMD python /home/username/something.py
```

Based on your comment, you can do the same thing with a bash script and run it using the CMD command in the dockerfile like this.

Your script will have the commands you want to run like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -c gunicorn_conf.py
```

And you can add this line to your docker file.

```
CMD /bash_script.sh
```

Comment: I edited the question showing that the container is running gunicorn. The `CMD` is reserved for starting the server. I think the question is not clear, I would like to run the logic of `import ete3` and the database build when the image is created, not as first step of running the container.

Comment: Based on your idea, I put my data prep command and the gunicorn command into a bash file and run that one `CMD /start_image.sh` . Thanks!

Comment: ah i just saw your comment, yeah i was going to suggest that next haha, will add it into my answer